# What is the point of JWT algorithm?

Tags: security, jwt

The jwt header looks like this:

```
{
    "alg": "HS256",
    "typ": "JWT"
}
```

This header will be Base64 encoded and encrypted.
So if you send the JWT to the server, the server already knows the algorithm how the JWT is encrypted. So what is the point of having "alg": "HS256"  . Also "typ":"JWT" actually you don't need that information as well. Server knows he will get a JWT. So is all this header just for documentation there ??

Comment: JWTs are not encrypted.

Comment: Yes you are right.                                                                                                        
Token = base64Header + '.' + base64Payload + '.' + signature